# What is this fruit tree that looks like lime and orange?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees

Can't remember what these are. They are no limes. They have a sweet sour taste. You can peel them and eat them, they are so good. Around December they turn yellowish orange color. Not oranges. Any ideas?

[image: IMG1][image: IMG2]

Comment: What location is this?

Comment: San Antonio Texas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already considered these:

They could be Calamansi. I can't find a good photo of the full tree of this though.

They could be Cam sanh (although your ones seem to have a smoother skin).